# reinventing the wheel : connection pool

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, connection-pooling

As a learning experience I am in the process of creating sort of an jdbc connection pool class for my java/jsf application. It's just to play around. I'm sure there are much more sophisticated ways to handle this.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "pooltje", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class pooltje {

    private Integer max_connecties = 10;
    private connectie[] pool = new connectie[max_connecties];

    public pooltje() {
        for (Integer teller = 0; teller < max_connecties; teller++) {
            pool[teller] = new connectie();
        }
    }

    public Synchronzed Connection borrow() {
        Connection ret_con = null;
        while (ret_con == null) {
            for (Integer t = 0; t < max_connecties; t++) {
                if (pool[t].getUsed() == Boolean.FALSE && ret_con == null) {
                    ret_con = pool[t].getConn();
                    pool[t].setUsed(Boolean.TRUE);
                }
            }
        }
        return ret_con;
    }

    public synchronized void giveback(Connection terug) {
        for (Integer t = 0; t < max_connecties; t++) {
            if (pool[t].getConn() == terug) {
                pool[t].setUsed(Boolean.FALSE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made the class a managed bean with application scope, so I know it will be instantiated only once at startup of the application.

My actual question is, how can I call the borrow and giveback method.
For the method borrow() I found the following:

```
FacesContext fc2 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Application app = fc2.getApplication();

Connection conn = (Connection) app.evaluateExpressionGet(fc2, "#{pooltje.borrow()}", Connection.class);
```

This works fine, however I feel that it should/could be easier. At least I do get a connection passed back.

For the method giveback() I have to pass a variable (the connection not to use anymore). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: And then not talking about the PHP-style... Readup some [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Reiterating Arjan, mixing various human languages in your code is definitely not clear, helpful or self-documenting to others (e.g. in order to get help here on Stack Overflow!). Use English all the way. Don't use Dutch street talk.

Comment: @Arjan Tijms and BalusC tanks for pointing that out. However something more fundamentally things must be wrong with my project setup. The suggestions made by BalusC are not working for me. Well, that's something sor another day. Anyway....thanks for your efforts.

Comment: You need to be more clear about what exactly is not working. Share the entire exception and stacktrace if you can. They tell really a lot about the cause of the problem. Perhaps you're trying to access it in bean's constructor which will indeed not work out?

Comment: @BalusC. Offcourse I understand you can't help me if I don't provide information. But....your comment and the one from Arjan Thijms convinced me to do it a little more structured manner. Posting a stacktrace of something I will not use any more seems a bit odd to me :-). So...still reinventing the wheel. For the connectionpool I will try to set up something like boneCP. (oh....and my naming was allready biting back. It was the source of a lot of confusion)

Answer (score 3):

The connection pool approach aside (or I would totally waste time doing a writeup along with detailed examples :/ ), you could just access other managed beans from inside a managed bean by injecting them as [`@ManagedProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html).

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ArbitraryBean {

    @ManagedProperty("pooltje")
    private Pooltje pooltje;

    // ... Add at least a setter for it.
}
```

This way you can just access it in your `@PostConstruct` or action methods whenever necessary:

```
public void doSomething() {
    Connection connection = pooltje.borrow();
    // ...
}
```

But really, a connection pool shouldn't be a JSF managed bean, and also not be designed that way. I basically entered this answer with my jaw wide open all the time .. I recommend to explore some existing open source connection pool libraries, such as [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/), if your sole purpose is to learn by example/exercise.

Comment: Thank you for replying (even in shock and awe). I am trying the suggestions right now. The BoneCP project I will defenitly explore. Indeed I'm learning by example/exercise.